# how to get url label from name of widget blogger

Tags: widget, blogger

my widget blogger name is **news** and its label and need him as link as example:

```
www.my url.blogspot.com/search/label/**news**
```

and when is change name widget to **Sport** the link become:

```
www.my url.blogspot.com/search/label/**Sport**
```

Thank you advance...

Comment: Please correct the language of this question. I can barely understand what you're asking.

Answer (score -2):

Copy the link and replace it with your blog name.

```
http://www.yourblog.blogspot.com/search/label/WidgetNameFoo
```